# Struggling with Fiddler and Security Challenges: Seeking Help in Java Replication

Tags: java, authentication, security, electron, fiddler

I am working on the authentication and protection against Fiddler and its counterparts simultaneously. I have found a lot of resources online that could help me with this, but I haven't achieved the desired results. Below, I have attached everything I have tried.

I also found an interesting piece of code on Github that uses ElectronJS and does exactly what I need. I attempted to replicate it in Java, but again, I was unsuccessful.

I hope you can help me; I have been struggling with this for a long time.

ElectronJS part (from [Github](https://github.com/overnote/over-javascript/blob/791c979f07cf7fac524e3c784805bc6f2ae90316/%E9%99%84%E5%BD%95-Electron/08.1-Electron%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98.md?plain=1#L91))

```js
    session.setCertificateVerifyProc((request, callback) => {
        if (request.certificate.issuer.commonName == 'DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot') {
            // 假设现在安装的是 Fiddler 的证书
            callback(-2) // 如果不符合预期，传入 -2 驳回
        } else {
            callback(-3) // -3 表示使用 Chromium 的验证结果，0 表示成功并禁止使用证书透明度验证
        }
    })
```

My attempt to replicate

```java
    SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("XXX", 443);
    socket.startHandshake();
    SSLSession session = socket.getSession();

    for (Certificate certificate : session.getPeerCertificates()) {
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificate;
        System.out.println(cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
        if (cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot")) {
            throw new SSLHandshakeException("Invalid certificate");
        }
    }
```

The result when Fiddler is not running

> CN=GlobalSign ECC OV SSL CA 2018, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
> CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
> CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE

The result when Fiddler is running

> CN=GlobalSign ECC OV SSL CA 2018, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE
> CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign ECC Root CA - R5
> CN=GlobalSign Root CA, OU=Root CA, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, C=BE

The Fiddler HTTPS certificate is installed, everything is good with that

And many, many other options, tried using not just getPeerCertificates, but for example getLocalCertificates, but it returned null